# Desktop simulation of shop-floor task queues

Tags: open-source, automation, simulation

I'm working on a shop-floor automation project, and I'd like to set up a desktop "queuing" simulation to help identify bottlenecks in our process.  Either Linux or Windows desktop software would be useful, and I suspect these platforms are amply represented [in available software packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_discrete_event_simulation_software).

The simulation doesn't need to be polished as we'll just be using it for internal evaluation and discussion as we write requirements for the project.  Essentially we will be looking for queues that grow too fast for the rest of the system to keep up.

I'm sure I can throw something ad hoc together (wasn't C++ originally motivated as a [Simula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) replacement?), but I'd be interested in recommendations based on the experience of others.

Comment: I think we'd need you to detail a more exact set of requirements for this to be answerable.

Comment: The point is not to write an industrial strength piece of software, but to have something flexible at the expense of robustness.  Queuing models are a staple of operations research and are [frequently the target of simulations](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pos/docs/pos-Seminar-15-02-2006_ppt.pdf).

Comment: @Caleb:  If you don't mind my asking, is the Question unanswerable (per your remark), or does it have "too many possible answers", or would "good answers.. be too long"?  Bear in mind that an Answer should recommend one (or at the most, a very few) softwares with which you have first-hand experience.

Comment: I think it would be hard to make and informed recommendation without a more clear cut set of criteria on which to judge what software best fit the use case.